# Java application getting slow with passage of time

Tags: java, performance, java-native-interface, proc

I have a Pro*C application that is calling Java module using JNI. The application performance is decreasing when it run continuously for one or two day. The memory usage remain in acceptable range. Can you please guide me how to investigate performance issue?

Comment: Can you profile the java application some how?  Is it spending more time garbage collecting as it has been on longer?

Answer (score 1):

I would use a profiler, or add timings for key phases in the application and log them.  You need to narrow down to what is getting slower over time.

It could be a data structure with is `O(n)` which is growing as you use it.

Answer (score 0):

I would do the following to start off with:

- Reproduce the problem on a test platform
- Take thread/memory dumps: see [here](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/Stacktrace/)
- Using [visualvm](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/visualvm/) to see what the memory heap looks like
- Start the app with `-verbose:gc` (see also [here](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/GCPortal/)) and check whether the frequency of garbage collections is increasing, which may be indicative of a memory leak).